# ios array.next exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am gettin an exception while running following code, code is

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];

    data=[MyDatabase new];
     imagearray=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name FROM interior":@"pic_name"];

    while([imagearray next])  /////Getting exception here
    {
       [mutablearray addObject:imagearray];
    }
```

and my exception is,

-[__NSArrayM next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
what is exact reason behind that ?

Comment: Why _should_ this work? Have you read the NSArray documentation? There is no next method, as the exception is telling you quite clearly.

Comment: It would probably be quicker to get a mutable copy of the `imagearray` array rather than enumerating `imagearray` and adding each item to a mutable array.  `mutablearray = [imagearray mutableCopy]` should do the trick.  Plus it should be noted that `imagearray` already appears to be a mutable array (`__NSArrayM`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];

 data=[MyDatabase new];
 imagearray=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name FROM interior":@"pic_name"];

 NSEnumerator *e = [imagearray objectEnumerator];
 id object;
 while (object = [e nextObject]) {
    [mutablearray addObject:object];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not enumerating correctly.

Example from the `NSArray` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectEnumerator):

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
id anObject;

while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    /* code to act on each element as it is returned */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[mutablearray addObjectsFromarray:imagearray];
```

instead of

```
while([imagearray next])  
{
   [mutablearray addObject:imagearray];
}
```